# View com tamanho dinâmico ajustável pelo usuário

Tags: android

Tenho um `LinearLayout` no qual preciso que o usuário ajuste seu tamanho dinamicamente. Basicamente seria apenas sua altura, podendo a largura ser um tamanho fixo, sendo `match_parent`.

A propriedade no qual seria alterada é o `android:layout_height`, através do método `onTouch`. Veja abaixo uma imagem que ilustra melhor a ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira ideia é identificar que foi clicado nas bordas, tanto *top* quanto *bottom*, depois arrastar essas bordas para que diminua o tamanho da *View*, para que tome um tamanho ideal de acordo com o usuário. Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Tem mesmo que ser nas bordas? Não pode ser em qualquer parte dentro?

Comment: @ramaral Consigo redirecionar normalmente a altura de baixo para cima. Na verdade,  não necessariamente precisa ser de cima para baixo. Só ajustar o tamanho de baixo para cima já é o suficiente. Até já fiz aqui, mas quero que o que a borda acompanhe o dedo, e o que está acontecendo é estou tendo um espaço entre a borda da view e o dedo. Estou fazendo a altura da view receber `((int) event.getRawY() - params.bottomMargin)`,... o problema aqui agora é só a lógica ^^